# 1x12 chain stability on chainring

Tags: 1x12

Aside (Trivia #1): The concept of offset just crept into the standard chainring jargon. When were chainrings with offset introduced?

[image: https://praxiscycles.com/product/mtn-dm-3-bolt-mtn-wave-tech/]

Context: Traditionally the teeth of a chainring were on the same plane as the mounting plane, but it is now necessary to specify that such a chainring has "zero offset". Chainrings that have 3mm offset and 6mm offset are also available.

Aside (Trivia #2): How lavish does the offset presently get? Are there, for instance, chainrings with 9mm or 10mm offset?

The objective of the offset is to make the chainring's teeth as aligned with the center *plane* of the cassette as possible. See black line on the right in the diagram below.

[image: chainring with/without offset]

If a chainring is installed with a *smaller* offset than needed (blue chainring; blue chainline), one runs the risk that the chain will fall off the chainring and onto the frame, potentially scratching or damaging the frame. The chain can potentially also jump up a gear or two.

Conversely, if a chainring is installed with a *larger* offset than needed (orange chainring; orange chainline), one runs the risk that the chain will fall onto the crankarms. The chain could also jump down a gear or two.

Both actions (climbing and torquing hard on the largest cog, or sprinting on the smallest) would become potentially dangerous events.

I'd like to determine whether 1x12 can be installed on a bike that came with 1x10 or 1x11. Let's take the "does the cassette fit the freehub" problem out of the equation. Let's assume it does, and just worry in this question whether the chain will stay firmly on the chainring.

Let's further assume that the chainring is dead-on center with the center of the cassette. Maybe we get some leeway there, but let's assume we nailed it. By the mere existence of the 1x12 cassette + chain/derailleur/shifter, along with using an appropriate sized chainring, we can assume that this system is workable.

The **only factor remaining** is the distance between the axis of the chainring (the spindle) and the axis of the cogs (the rear-wheel hub).

Question: (#3) How do I determine the minimum distance between crank and hub for a 1x12 system?

Companion Question (#4): If the distance satisfies a minimum constraint, it only remains to be sure that no spacer is missing from the cassette, and that the offset is accurate. Can one eyeball that the chainring is centered between cog number 6 and cog number 7, or does this require calculating the dimensions of the various parts?

Companion Question (#5): chainrings appear to exist in just 0mm, 3mm, and 6mm offsets. Does this express the tolerances? If, for instance, the mid-line is at 1mm, we'd use 0mm; if it's at 2mm, we'd use 2mm; and if it's at 1.5mm, it's a toss. In other words, we can be acceptably as far as 1.5 mm from the center plane of the cassette.

I'm here only asking #3, but if you know the answers to #1, #2, #4, and #5, please do tell us in your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Offset itself is a result of bikes having many different chainlines. Instead of making four versions of every crank arm model for each of the standard chainlines (and then another couple variations of each thereof for the different arm lengths), it is more efficient to change the chainring, which is a much simpler part to make. Not all brands do this (eg. Shimano), but many do.

(#1) I'm guessing the wide proliferation in offsets came around 2015-2016, when bikes with Boost rear ends were first sold. I know 10s Shimano MTB only comes in one chainline option, but I'm not sure about the SRAM counterpart.

(#2) I think the most offset ring that's commonly available is a 6mm, used to go from 56.5mm superboost to 50.5mm non-boost-ish.

(#3) mattnz addressed this excellently in their answer.

(#4) I've actually heard the argument that chainline should be biased towards the larger cogs by a few mm if possible. The reasoning is that most climbing is done in the larger cogs, and so the efficiency benefits of a straighter chainline would be beneficial there. I am not sure if having your chainline centered to tenths of a mm is actually helpful.

(#5) Bikes are designed for one of several standard chainlines: 49mm for QR135 or TA142 rear ends, 52 or 55 for TA148, and 56.5 for "superboost" TA157 MTBs. It's not like chainline is a continually variable thing that you have to pick the best matching chainring offset for.

Also, chainrings used to be entirely made from a stamped metal sheet. Nowadays, only the cheapest chainrings are. Higher-end models are all machined or otherwise made in multiple steps, which allows for offset to be more easily incorporated.

Answer (score 3):

Really a fairly complex question asking a whole lot of detail about a really complex problem. The simple answer is to refer to the  manufacturer documentation, their engineers have solved the thought experiment for you.

SRAM state a minimum length of 425 mm for the MTB group sets. [Refer here](https://www.sram.com/globalassets/document-hierarchy/frame-fit-specifications/mtb/2021-mtb-frame-fit-specifications.pdf)

For the groupset and frame manufacturers, they calculate. With modern components and frames, if you buying the right kit that is specified as compatible, and assembling it, you won't even need to eyeball, it will be correct.  If you are mixing and matching and making a custom or franken-bike from road and mountain parts (or you own frame), you are best to calculate it, but eyeballing will likely be accurate.  The closer your frame chain stay length to the magic length (425mm in SRAMs case), the more accurate your chainline will need to be, but there is already a reasonable amount of tolerance designed into the system.